# Change an entry in a vector to reach a target value of a function in R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
z <- c(3,4,22,1,323,42,4,04,99,9,24,76,1)
target_mean <- 55
```

My question is: what value of z[1] (first entry in z) gets me my target mean?
The answer is 106 (I checked it by manually changing z[1]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option that will be faster for long `z`:

```
target_mean * length(z) - sum(z[-1]) 
# [1] 106
```

Input

```
z <- c(3,4,22,1,323,42,4,04,99,9,24,76,1)
target_mean <- 55
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Pretty simple stuff.

```
for (i in 1:150){
  z[1] = i
  if(mean(z) == 55){
    print(i)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
> (target_mean - mean(z)) * length(z) + z[1]
[1] 106
```